# Is this a logical way to log real time data into a database?

Tags: python, database, django, web-services, database-design

**Reworded Question**
Are there other (common) solutions to log real time data that will be consumed via client side web applications?

**Background**
I have a web application running on a small embedded Linux machine.  It will have a number daughter cards connected to it used to monitor / control other devices.  There are separate processes running to control the various IO and interface to the client side via Websockets.  Since the only interface to the user is via HTML, retrieving data, plotting data, etc makes the most sense to me to pull it from a database rather than the raw filesystem (which I have done before for rich client software).

**Concerns**
While my proposed schema minimizes the size of the database, should there be a performance concern having the `LogSample` table being huge?  Assuming a 1Hz sample rate running 8 hours a day: `3600 samples * 8 hours * 10 LogValues = 288000 LogSamples / day`.

**Proposed Database Schema**

```
LogRecord
---------
  + Name
  + Start
  + Stop
  + Notes
  - LogValues ----> LogValues
                    ---------
                      + Name
                      + Units
                      + Sample Rate
                      - Samples ----> LogSample
                                      ---------
                                        + Time Stamp
                                        + Value
```

Where:

- Underlined names are independent tables
- `---->` represents a 1 to many relationship
- Sample rate will be a max of 5Hz (currently planned at 1Hz)
- Time stamp will be an int representing # of samples since the start time

**System Information**
Max Connected Users: 15
Database: sqlite3 or PostgreSQL
OS: Ubuntu 13.04
Web Framework / ORM: Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer to this question relies on the following decision:

#### Is this data Ephemeral?

If yes, you are better off pushing your samples into something like RabbitMQ for consumption by websocket connected clients, or use an existing solution such as statsd+graphite. This will remove a lot of the storage/performance concerns from postgres, and put them in software designed to handle these usecases.

#### Does this data need to be available forever?

Stay with Postgres, but make sure that you use append-only semantics as much as possible (this means don't continuously write to `LogRecord.Stop`). I would also have a secondary data channel such as Redis Pub-Sub queues for distributing results to real-time clients. If you're doing continuous writes and polling at the same time, it's a recipe for performance bottlenecks.

**Appendix:** I think your schema map is backwards. To maintain consistency and the invariant of 1 LogRecord to Many LogFields (etc. for LogField -> LogSample), you would want the following structure:

```
LogRecord <--,  LogField <--,  LogSample
---------    |  ---------   |  ---------
+ Name       `--+ Record    `--+ Field
+ Start         + Name         + Time Stamp
+ Stop          + Units        + Value
+ Notes         + Sample Rate
```

Also, follow this simple tutorial for setting up Postgres for performance:

- Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yhfW1BDOSQ
- Slides: http://thebuild.com/presentations/not-your-job.pdf

Comment: The data is logging real time data during a process (to be viewed later if an issue arises), this is what lead me to an SQL database.  In general there will only ever be 1 writer (logging the data) and 1 or 2 consumers looking at past data.  The data needs to last as long as the flash storage, so I agree about postgres.  Thanks for the tips on postgres performance.  You're drawn schema is what I had in my head, just digitize it well.